# Same Change event to all comboboxes

Tags: vba, userform

I am a VBA noob, so all help is welcome.
I have several `Combobox`s in the same `UserForm`. The `Items` in every `Combobox` are loaded in `Userform_Inialize`. The color of the `Combobox` will change depending on the item you choose.

Is there a way to apply the same `Change` event to all `Combobox`s or a "dim" of some sort? To avoid coding 200 `If`s.

Comment: Write a sub which takes a combobox as a parameter argument - put all the logic there.  Then call that sub from each of your combobox event handlers, passing in the specific combobox.

Comment: Just curious, say ComboBox1 has items cb1-01, cb1-02 and cb1-03 and ComboBox2 has items : cb2-01, cb2-02 and cb2-03. When a user choose cb1-01 item and you already write the code that if cb1-01 is selected then the background color of ComboBox1 change to red, did you mean (A) you want ComboBox2 background color automatically change to red also ? Or did you mean (B) you want ComboBox2 certain item (say, cb2-03) automatically is selected and the background color of ComboBox2 is changed to (say) green? So selecting cb1-01 give result : ComboBox1 red, ComboBox2 green with cb-03 selected.

Comment: If you have 200 `If`'s then you really should consider storing your item<>color combinations somewhere other than hard-coded in your VBA.  For example on a worksheet if you're using Excel, or in a table in Access.

Comment: Tim Williams - Ty but like i said i am a reaaly noob not a pogrammer or developer just a guy trying to improve day to day tasks in adfmnistrative work. Can you give me an example of what you described ABout a paramter argument?

Comment: karma- I have something like this: All combobox import their list when the form initialize (The List of itemisthe same for every combobox). lets call the items "a",,"b", etc....Then i coded this: Private sub ComboBox1.chage() If ComboBox1.Text="a" then comboBox1.Backcolor=COLORCODE1 ENd If If comboBox1.Text="b" then combobox1.BackColor=COLORCODE2 ENd If .... End Sub. But i want this for all comboboxes is there a simpler faster way to this without having to code this for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Write a sub which takes a combobox as a parameter argument - put all the logic there. Then call that sub from each of your combobox event handlers, passing in the specific combobox.

Like this:

```vb
Private sub ComboBox1_change() 
    CheckValue ComboBox1
End Sub

Private sub ComboBox2_change() 
    CheckValue ComboBox2
End Sub

'check value of `cbo` and assign backcolor as appropriate
Sub CheckValue(cbo As Object)
    Select Case cbo.Text
        Case "a": cbo.Backcolor=COLORCODE1
        Case "b": cbo.Backcolor=COLORCODE2
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG Tim Williams this is perfect and working like a charm...thank you so much.